# Не отображается изображение в React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Прописал import и отобразил все в самом атрибуте. Вроде все логично и должно работать, но почему-то браузер его (изображение) не отображает. Если я, допустим, укажу неправильную директорию, то сам реакт начинает ругаться, что ошибка синтаксиса, из этого следует, что путь указан верно. Сам я новичок в Реакте, не понимаю в чем дело..введите сюда описание изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код вашего фрагмента текстом, для этого можно нажать "править" ниже вашего вопроса

Answer (score -1):

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Вместо импорта прописал директорию в самой функции и все заработало
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXTP5.png